# test method of RegExp GWT/Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex, gwt

I want to detect if a `String` is a decimal by using a regular expression. My question is more on how to use the regular expression mechanism than detecting that a `String` is a decimal. I use the `RegExp` class provided by `GWT`.

```
        String regexDecimal = "\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?";
        RegExp regex = RegExp.compile(regexDecimal);
        String[] decimals = { "one", "+2", "-2", ".4", "-.4", ".5", "2.5" };
        for (int i = 0; i < decimals.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(decimals[i] + " "
                    + decimals[i].matches(regexDecimal) + " "
                    + regex.test(decimals[i]) + " "
                    + regex.exec(decimals[i]));
        }
```

The output:

```
one false false null
+2 false true 2
-2 false true 2
.4 false true 4
-.4 false true 4
.5 false true 5
2.5 true true 2.5
```

I was expecting that both methods `String.matches()` and `RegExp.test()` return the same result.

1. So what's the difference between
   both methods?
2. How to use the `RegExp.test()` to get the same behaviour?

Comment: Both answers are good and fixed my problem, so now which one do I accept since they are basically the same answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the regex to

```
"^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$"
```

*explain*

double escape is because we're in Java...

regex start with `^` to forces the regex to match from the very start of the string.

regex end with `$` to forces the regex to match from the very end of the string.

this is how you should get String.matches() to do the same as GWT RegExp.test()

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the difference, but I would say that `RegExp.test()` is correct, because your regex matches as soon as there is a digit within your string and `String.matches()` behaves like there where anchors around the regex.

```
\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?
```

Your non capturing group is optional, so one `\\d` (`[0-9]`) is enough to match, no matter what is around.

When you add anchors to your regex, that means it has to match the string from the start to the end, then `RegExp.test()` will probably show the same results.

```
^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$
```